# How to send file to dropzone using ruby and selenium-webdriver?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

[Here is the web with file dropzone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQCk1.png)

I was trying to upload an image file like this:

```
filename = '6.png'
file = File.join(Dir.pwd, filename)
@driver.find_element(:id, "project_images_dropzone").send_key file
```

But it does not work.
I also tried drag and drop:

```
filename = '6.png'
file = File.join(Dir.pwd, filename)
target = @driver.find_element(:id, "project_images_dropzone")
@driver.action.click_and_hold(file).perform
@driver.action.drag_and_drop(file,target).perform
@driver.action.release.perform
```

... but this method does not work too.
Is someone know the solution of my problem?

In the code of the page hidden input I found:

```
<input class="dz-hidden-input" multiple="multiple" accept="image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/png" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; height: 0px; width: 0px;" type="file">
```

Again, I tried to send the file with the first method, but webdriver can't find this element:

```
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.3.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:69:in `assert_ok': Unable to locate element: #dz\-hidden\-input (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution by myself. All I had to do was locate the hidden input field using xpath. It works great. Here's what it looks like:

```
And(/^I upload an image$/) do
  filename = '6.png'
  file = File.join(Dir.pwd, filename) #Dir.pwd is the same folder where .rb file is
  @driver.find_element(:xpath, "html/body/input").send_key file #hidden input field
end
```